# Filter Dictionnary<string,string> that do not have their keys in an array string[]

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following objects:

```
IDictionary<string, string> foo = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "key1", "somerandomvalue" },
    { "key2", "somerandomvalue" },
    { "key3", "somerandomvalue" },
    { "key4", "somerandomvalue" }
}

public static readonly string[] bar = {
    "key1",
    "key3"
};
```

I would like to filter the Dictionary foo and keep the item that have their keys in the Array bar. So we'll have something like that:

```
bar: {
    { "key1", "somerandomvalue" },
    { "key3", "somerandomvalue" }
}
```

I have tried the following but dont understand why the k variable is flagged as char type

```
foo
    .Where(k => x.Key.Any(x => bar.Contains(x.ToString())))
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: `.Where(k => x.Key.Any(...))`  There's actually no `x` in current context

Comment: `.Where(k => bar.Contains(k.Key))`

Comment: You have duplicate keys in your dictionary ("key1"), which won't work. And your LINQ expression won't compile (`k => x.Key...` Decide on `k` or `x`).

Comment: `x.Key.Any` takes the string `Key` and makes it an `IEnumerable<char>`, then applies `Any` to it. That's why the `x` is a `char` in there.

Comment: From what @HereticMonkey mentioned, I would recommend something like a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>` to hold these details and or `List<Values>`etc...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes you're right there is a typo.. The dictionary have distinct keys. I will edit my post

Comment: @Cid I'll have a look thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use need to use `Any` in `Where` function by your key collection `bar`.

```
foo.Where(x=> bar.Any(b => b == x.Key)).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```